# What is double V model testing?

Tags: testing

I understand that in the V model testing there is a corresponding test for every level of specification/design. Then what is the double V model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more usually called the [W model](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/Software-Development-Models/Software_Development_Models_W_Model.html) (probably because VV looks a lot like W in most fonts) and it is an intermediate development model between the Waterfall model and Agile development that has more emphasis on testing at early stages than Waterfall.

The difference between V and W models is not *what* tests are done, but rather *when* they are done. This is advantageous as the development of specifications and tests is a difficult and error-prone task in itself, and so it is impractical to try to separate them (in time) totally from the coding of the program itself.

Comment: It just occurred to me that “double V” might also be so called because of how the Germans pronounce the letter “W”. Combine that with someone listening over the phone or something like that and you get the somewhat-odd naming scheme…

Comment: There is also the Triple V too if interested.

https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/blog/using-v-models-for-testing/